# Exception thrown: read access violation. std::shared_ptr<>::operator-><,0>(...)->**** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7

Tags: c++, winapi

Good afternoon to all! I am writing a game engine using `OpenGL + Win32 / GLFW`. Therefore, I will say the project is large, but I have a problem that has led me to a dead end and I can't understand what the problem is. The problem is that I have a `shared_ptr<Context>` in the 'windows' class (it is platform-based) that is responsible for the context (GL, D3D). And everything works fine when I launch the application, everything is drawn normally, but when I start entering the cursor into the window, a crash occurs when any function calls from context, in my case is:

```cpp
context->swapBuffers();
```

Here a crash:

```
std::shared_ptr<Context>::operator-><Context,0>(...)->**** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7.
```

Then I got into the callstack and saw that the `context->` itself is non-zero, so the function should be called.

[image]

Then I searched for a long time for the problem and found that when I remove the Win32 message processing code, and when I remove it, errors do not occur when calling a function from `context->`. I removed everything unnecessary from the loop and left only the basic functions and tried to run it like this, because I thought that some other functions inside were causing this problem, but no.

```cpp
while (PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
```

That is, when I delete `TranslateMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()`, the error goes away. And then I finally got confused i.e I don't understand what is happening. And then I thought that maybe somehow the operating system itself affects that pointer, prohibits reading or something like that.
And then I paid attention to `__vtptr` in the call stack, and noticed that it is `nullptr`, and moreover it has the `void**` type. And also the strangest thing is that in the error I have `->**** was 0xffffffffffffffc7` as many as four consecutive pointers. What is it?

[image]

I understand I practically didn't throw off the code, because I have a big project and I think it doesn't make sense to throw everything, so I tried to explain the problem by roughly showing what is happening in my code. I will be grateful to everyone who will help :)

Comment: Are you sure that the object holding `context` is still alive? Looks like use-after-free to me. Compile the program with sanitizers - `address, undefined, memory` are really helpful for tracking down these kind of bugs.

Comment: Yes, I'm kind of sure that `context` alive, because the error occurs only when windows messages start to be processed, absolutely any. Maybe the OS clears it or shuffles it temporarily and then back again, but in the meantime, `context` try call the function.

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7` is almost guaranteed to be the address resulting from dereferencing a null pointer and then indexing into the structure the dynamic type refers to. Since this is the result of subtracting from a null pointer (`0 - 25`) it's most likely the heap implementation trying to access its bookkeeping information, which it commonly stores right before the actual allocated memory area.

Comment: OS will never move around your pointers, that is nonsensical. Triple check all lines which initialize, use, delete `context`, you can set a *on-write* breakpoint.

Comment: @IInspectable I think I probably solved the problem I had a pointer to a `Window` in the `Context` in which there was also a smart pointer to the `Context` again. And I tried to remove the raw pointer on the window in the context and there are no crashes yet.